# Word document places text inside rows

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Every single document my collegue creates has some sort of view that forces his lines to appear in row-like entities. He would like to somehow turn it off.

[image: office screen]

We are both using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 on Windows 10 Enterprise and have not experienced anything like that before. Old documents behave as expected.

Comment: It would appear the person has changed their main Word template to include a table.  Here is a set of step: (several sources):  Quit Word.
Press Win+E to summon a File Explorer window.
Type %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.
Right-click on the Normal.dotm file.
The file might show only the first part of the name, Normal.
Choose the Rename command from the shortcut menu.
Edit the name to Normal-old.dotm or Normal-old.
If you can see the dotm part of the name, don’t change it.
Press Enter to lock in the new name.
Keep the File Explorer window open.
Restart Word.

Comment: Well, I did everything as instructed but unfortunately it did not work :/.

Comment: Perhaps uninstall, restart and then install Office again. Patch fully and make sure both the Normal Style and the Normal.dot template are both default.  Also try a different Windows User Account. Office is susceptible to  User Profile damage

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will call it a day though. I have no time for reinstalling the software due to the minor inconvenience. But if by any chance anything less invasive comes to your mind, I will gladly try it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you may run Word in safe mode to check this issue. Please type "winword /safe" in Run dialog and click OK. Then create a blank document type text.

**If the problem still occurs in safe mode of Word**, and renaming Normal.dotm does not work, maybe you need to refer to [reset user options and registry settings in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word). There is a EasyFix tool in "Here's an easy fix" section, you may try it to have a check.

In addition, you could delete the Word registry keys under the path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word manually according to this article. Please note, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.
Please refer to this article about how to back up and restore the registry in Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756.

If the steps does not work, I would like to suggest you repair Office. Right-click the Start button Windows 10 (lower-left corner), and select Apps and Features on the pop-up menu. Select the Microsoft Office 2016, and select Modify. Generally, Office ProPlus 2016 is MSI-based install, you could select Repair and then click Continue in Change your installation.

Or you could try to uninstall Office and reinstall it.

**If the problem does not occur in safe mode of Word**, it's recommended to check add-ins. Please go to File > Options > Add-ins > Word Add-ins and COM Add-ins > GO, remove or uncheck the boxes of add-ins.

You may also go to %programfiles%\Microsoft Office\office16\Startup, check if there is any add-in and remove it. (If you are using 32-bit on 64-bit Windows 10, please go to %programfiles%\Microsoft Office\office16\Startup)

Comment: Well, that's a really comprehensive guide. Will test out some of the easygoing solutions in the meantime and see back to you if it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, so we tried the above solution in order to check whether the problem occurs in safe mode. And it does not. However, there are no checked add-ins and the only one present is OneNote notes, which I doubt is the reason for this issue. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the only solution here is to reinstall the software, which would probably work but is not an option. I will mark your answer as accepted untill (if ever) more suitable one emerges. Thank you for your effort.